# Error in building default .NET Core console application targeting the full .NET framework 4.6.2

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I have been trying to learn the basics of programming for .NET Core using the .NET Core CLI tools. I downloaded the .NET Core SDK for Windows version 1.0.1 and followed the simple instructions on the download page (https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows):

```
mkdir hwapp
cd hwapp
dotnet new
dotnet restore
dotnet run
```

This compiles and runs fine on my Windows 10, x64 machine.

I run into trouble when I try to target the .NET Framework 4.6.2 in the same application. From what I have read, I should only have to add a node with value "net462" under the "frameworks" node:

```
{
  "net462": {}
}
```

Yet, after adding this node, running the dotnet restore and then the dotnet build CLI commands, I get the following error:

```
Project hwapp (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing
Compiling hwapp for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe compile-csc @C:\Development\dotNet\hwapp\obj\Debug\net462\dotnet-compile.rsp returned Exit Code 1
C:\Development\dotNet\hwapp\obj\Debug\net462\dotnet-compile.assemblyinfo.cs(2,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Development\dotNet\hwapp\obj\Debug\net462\dotnet-compile.assemblyinfo.cs(3,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Development\dotNet\hwapp\obj\Debug\net462\dotnet-compile.assemblyinfo.cs(4,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Development\dotNet\hwapp\obj\Debug\net462\dotnet-compile.assemblyinfo.cs(5,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Development\dotNet\hwapp\obj\Debug\net462\dotnet-compile.assemblyinfo.cs(2,58): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
C:\Development\dotNet\hwapp\obj\Debug\net462\dotnet-compile.assemblyinfo.cs(3,54): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
C:\Development\dotNet\hwapp\obj\Debug\net462\dotnet-compile.assemblyinfo.cs(4,67): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
C:\Development\dotNet\hwapp\obj\Debug\net462\dotnet-compile.assemblyinfo.cs(5,62): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
C:\Development\dotNet\hwapp\Program.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Development\dotNet\hwapp\Program.cs(5,18): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
C:\Development\dotNet\hwapp\Program.cs(7,33): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
C:\Development\dotNet\hwapp\Program.cs(7,23): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported

Compilation failed.
    0 Warning(s)
    12 Error(s)
```

As you can read from the output, when targeting the .NET Framework 4.6.2, the compiler does not seem to be able to find the System namespace. This same error appears when I try to target earlier .NET Frameworks like 4.6.1 and 4.5.2.

I have tried moving a copy of the x64 version of System.dll and mscorlib.dll from the GAC to the C:\Program Files\dotnet\ directory so that the csc.exe program can find the System namespace with no success.

If it would be helpful, please find the contents of my project.json file below:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "net462": {},
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.1"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your project.json works fine for me. Do you have [.NET Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack](http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html) installed?

Comment: Installing the .NET Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack solved the issue! Thanks @svick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to target .Net 4.6.2, you need to install the [.NET Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack](http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html).

Comment: This answer worked exactly as prescribed.

To push the issue a bit further though... could you point me in the direction of any literature detailing why the Developer Pack needed to be installed in order for the .NET Core app to properly target the .NET Framework 4.6.2?

I already had this .NET version installed on my machine. What did installing the Developer Pack do so that 
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe compile-csc
can work with the .NET Framework 4.6.2?

Comment: Not sure if this is documented somewhere, but generally installing a version of .Net Framework only gives you the runtime assemblies (used to run applications). The various Developer/Targetting packs give you *reference assemblies* (used to compile code).

Comment: That makes sense. Since I am trying to develop on a new machine without Visual Studio, my initial efforts were left wanting due to my mistaken expectation brought about by using Visual Studio which provides the libraries to compile code against different versions of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Surprising/frustrating that this isn't installed by default in a VS2017 w/ ".NET desktop development" role installed, considering that 4.6.2 is the required/expected framework for .NET Standard 1.5: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library#net-platforms-support